# How can I display Latitude & Longitude in 19.0176° N, 72.8562° E format in Objective c

Tags: objective-c, iphone, core-location, latitude-longitude

I am using the following code to get the current location,I have added the Corelocation framework

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}



- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{

     NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);

    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {


        NSInteger degrees = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;

        double decimal = fabs(newLocation.coordinate.latitude - degrees);

        int minutes = decimal * 60;

        double seconds = decimal * 3600 - minutes * 60;

        NSString *lattitudeStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d° %d' %1.4f\"",
                                  degrees, minutes, seconds];

        _latitudeLabel.text = lattitudeStr;

        degrees = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;

        decimal = fabs(newLocation.coordinate.longitude - degrees);

        minutes = decimal * 60;

        seconds = decimal * 3600 - minutes * 60;

        NSString *longitudeStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d° %d' %1.4f\"",
                                  degrees, minutes, seconds];

        _longitudeLabel.text = longitudeStr;


    }

     // Stop Location Manager
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

    NSLog(@"Resolving the Address");
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^
     (NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)

 {
        NSLog(@"Found placemarks: %@, error: %@", placemarks, error);

        if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) 
{
            placemark = [placemarks lastObject];

            _addressLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@ %@\n%@\n%@",
                                   placemark.thoroughfare,
                                  placemark.postalCode, placemark.locality,
                                  placemark.administrativeArea,
                                  placemark.country];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
        }
    } ];

}
```

I am getting the values for,Latitude:19° 1’ 3.4129” and Longitude:72° 51’ 22.1918” So I need this coordinate display in 19.0176° N,72.8562° E format in Objective c. How to get the exact latitude and longitude. where i am doing the mistake or do i need to add any other method or function or framework or sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have these values, see the comment `this is what you want`

```
if (currentLocation != nil) {


        NSInteger degrees = newLocation.coordinate.latitude; //<--- this is what you want

        NSString *lattitudeStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f° N",
                                  degrees];

        _latitudeLabel.text = lattitudeStr;

        degrees = newLocation.coordinate.longitude; //<--- this is what you want


        NSString *longitudeStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f° E",
                                  degrees];

        _longitudeLabel.text = longitudeStr;


    }
```

Comment: I need to display my lat & long  in 19.0176° N, 72.8562° E format. Display as same

Comment: need to display direction

Answer (score 0):

```
  NSString *lat = [self convertCoordinateFromDegreeMinuteSecond:@"19° 1’ 3.4129”" position:@"N"];
  NSString *lon = [self convertCoordinateFromDegreeMinuteSecond:@"72° 51’ 22.1918”" position:@"E"];


  - ( NSString * )convertCoordinateFromDegreeMinuteSecond:( NSString * )string position:( NSString * )position; {
  NSCharacterSet *notAllowedChars = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789."] invertedSet];

  NSArray *arrayLat = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

  if ( arrayLat.count == 3 ) {
      NSString *degree = [[arrayLat[ 0 ] componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:notAllowedChars] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
      NSString *minute = [[arrayLat[ 1 ] componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:notAllowedChars] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
      NSString *second = [[arrayLat[ 2 ] componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:notAllowedChars] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

      int    sign       = degree.doubleValue < 0 ? -1 : 1;
      double coordinate = ( degree.doubleValue + ( sign * ( minute.doubleValue / 60. ) ) + ( sign * ( second.doubleValue / 3600. ) ) );

      NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f° %@", coordinate, position];
      return str;

  } else {
      return @"NaN";
  }
}
```

Comment: if this code works for you, please up or vote :) Thanks.